# Extracting Reviews of one particular app from Google Play Store using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
from time import sleep
from webbrowser import Chrome

import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

class FindByXpathCss():

    def test(self):
        baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
        id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("F:\\Chrome-webdriver\\chromedriver")
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(baseUrl)
```

Here I need to click on one button (Full review) to view the full review text.

```
        fullReviewbtn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#fcxH9b > div.WpDbMd > c-wiz > div > 
        div.ZfcPIb > div > div.JNury.Ekdcne > div > div > div.W4P4ne > div:nth-child(2) > div > 
        div:nth-child(2) > div > div.d15Mdf.bAhLNe > div.UD7Dzf > span:nth-child(1) > div > 
        button').click()

        sleep(1)
```

Here we are reading that full review text using an xpath, but I wish to read all other reviews of
the app, around 1200 reviews for this app alone. I wish to know how can i iterate it using for 
loop here.

```
        elementByXpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
        [@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]').text

        if elementByXpath is not None:
            print("We found an element using Xpath")
        #Review = elementByXpath.get_attribute("Review")
        print(elementByXpath)
        driver.close()

ff = FindByXpathCss()
ff.test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
class FindByXpathCss():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.maximize_window()
        baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true"
        driver.get(baseUrl)

        scrolls = 15
        while True:
            scrolls -= 1
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
            time.sleep(3)
            if scrolls < 0:
                break

        elemtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'RveJvd snByac')]")))
        elemtn.click()

        scrolls = 5
        while True:
            scrolls -= 1
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
            time.sleep(3)
            if scrolls < 0:
                break

        elemtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'RveJvd snByac')]")))
        elemtn.click()
        reviewText = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")))

        # reviewText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")
        for textreview in reviewText:
            print textreview.text
```

Comment: Thank u Dipak, it worked well, but still one more concern, I am still unable to get all reviews completely, I have tried to change xpath and css selectors also, but still only fetching around 160 reviews, but still 500+ more reviews are there to fetch, any help would be appreciated please..
    revtext = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#fcxH9b>div.WpDbMd>c-wiz> div>div.ZfcPIb>div>div.JNury.Ekdcne>div>div>div.W4P4ne>div:nth-child(2)')
    #reviewText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[2]/span[1]")
    for textrev in reviewText:
        Reviewstxt.append(textrev.text)

Comment: Still it is not giving all the reviews of the app.

Comment: Yes because DOM is dynamic and also if you check DOM properly few reviews dont have Full Review button associted with it. I will cherck it